# Jira4R: The watchers field in Jira 5.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jira

Our JIRA administrator recently upgraded up from JIRA 4.* to Jira 5.1. A few of us have webapps written to use the JIRA soap API, and i'm using Jira4R ruby gem.

The watchers field broke with this upgrade. Previously I'd issue the following through jira4r:

```
JIRA_WATCHER_FIELD = "customfield_10060"
JIRA_WATCHERS = ["me", "prod.mgr", "vendor.management"]

    issue.customFieldValues= [
        JiraTicket.create_custom_field(JIRA_WATCHER_FIELD, JIRA_WATCHERS),
    ]

    issue = jira.createIssue(issue)
```

All of a sudden, this returns:
Failed to create jira ticket: com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: Custom field ID 'customfield_10060' is invalid.

So I guess that this isn't a custom field anymore. It doesn't look like it's part of Jira4R::RemoteIssue yet either.

Has anyone found a way to get it to work? I'm thinking about making my own fork of Jira4R and making the backward incompatible change to the gem.

Answer (score 0):

"Watchers" field was never a custom field in JIRA. My guess is that you had [JIRA Watcher Field Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugin.workflow.jira-watcher-field) installed. This plugin actually adds "watchers" as a custom field. Maybe after the JIRA upgrade that plugin was no longer compatible and the field was gone.

Ask your JIRA administrator to check if you had that plugin installed and if he can upgrade the plugin too to make it work with your upgraded JIRA. After that, ask him to confirm if "10060" is the ID of that field (it could change if you reinstall the plugin).